# Create a fixed footer in Ant Design

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I want to accomplish something like this with a fixed footer.

```
--------------------------------
|          HEADER              | 
--------------------------------
|       |                      |
|       |                      |
| SIDE  |       CONTENT        |
|  BAR  |                      |
|       |                      |
--------------------------------
|          FOOTER              | 
--------------------------------
```

[I'm using Ant Design layout](https://ant.design/components/layout/) and I added a position fixed to the footer but I'm getting a weird bug when the sidebar groups are expanded that block some of the sidebar links.
[image: bug]

Here is an example:

https://codepen.io/HugoLiconV/pen/jONBLJQ?editors=0010

EDIT:
The main problem is that if I expand the sidebar group that says "expand me" because there is a lot of links, the footer will hide some of the links. This happens especially a 1366 x 768 resolution
[image: not expanded]
[image: expanded]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a codepen link https://codepen.io/sniperdumbooo/pen/pozeZJb?editors=0010 for how you wanted to achieve with a fixed footer and centered content and sidebar big fixed

The changes made are removed display: 'flex' from footer and added textAlign: 'center' to the header part and added textAlign: 'justify' to the center body as:

```
<Header style={{ background: '#DDD', padding: 0, textAlign: 'center' }} >Header</Header>

<Footer style={{ 
        borderTop: '1px solid #e8e8e8',
        position: 'fixed',
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        textAlign: 'center'}} >

textAlign: 'justify'  ### to the div inside the <Content />
```

And the blocked sidebar links when expanded is due to the position: 'fixed' in the

```
 <Layout style={{
    overflow: 'auto',
    minHeight: '100vw',  ## make it minHeight: '100vw'
    width: '100%',
    left: 0      ### Removed the position: 'fixed'
  }}>
```

Also remove style="padding: 24px" from div in html id="container"

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

will give you what you want to achieve with the bug fixed as in this link of codepen : [Desired solution](https://codepen.io/sniperdumbooo/pen/pozeZJb?editors=0010)

Comment: This works in a 1080 resolution, but not in a 1366 x 768

Comment: Hey @HugoLicon checkout this edited codepen link https://codepen.io/sniperdumbooo/pen/pozeZJb?editors=0010 hope this solves that issue I have changed the height: 100vw to minHeight: 100vw and it's working please check

Comment: @HugoLicon did you check this link https://codepen.io/sniperdumbooo/pen/pozeZJb?editors=0010

Answer (score 2):

hi i red all answers and i think there is an easier way for only using antd instead of using extra css

just use this kind of affix around your footer :

```
<Affix offsetBottom={0}>
```

and the document if you need :
https://ant.design/components/affix/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Tyler2P thanks honey im new here i just forgot to check if code exists

Answer (score 1):

You can add margin bottom same as footer height in px , please add below css and check,

```css
.ant-layout-sider-children {
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: -0.1px;
    padding-top: 0.1px;
    margin-bottom: 95px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this can not (easily) be solved with CSS, and your best bet is to simply move the footer out one level, to the bottom of the **parent** `<Layout>`:

```
<Layout> <!-- Core layout -->
    <Layout> <!-- Layout with Header and Content --> 
    </Layout>
    <Footer style={{ 
        borderTop: '1px solid #e8e8e8',
        position: 'fixed',
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        textAlign: 'center',
        display: 'flex',}}
        >
        Ant Design ©2018 Created by Ant UED
    </Footer>
</Layout>
```

This can be seen [here](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/KKPWXVL?editors=0010).

Comment: ok, but the problem remains. if you expand the groups, some of them will be hidden by the footer

Answer (score 0):

Here, i have made a little change in your footer css and it looks fine.

```
  <Footer style={{ 
        borderTop: '1px solid #e8e8e8',
        position: 'fixed',
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        textAlign: 'center',}}
   >
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

I had figured out a hack solution

```
import React, { FC, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';

import { Table } from 'antd';
import { useMeasure } from 'react-use';

...

export const App: FC = () => {

  const dataSource = ...
  const columns = ...
  ...

  /** Render */
  const [ref, { height }] = useMeasure<HTMLDivElement>();
  const tableTitleRef = useRef<Element>();
  const tableHeaderRef = useRef<Element>();
  const tableBodyRef = useRef<Element>();
  const tableFooterRef = useRef<Element>();

  const refs = (e: HTMLDivElement) => {
    ref(e);
    // 攔截 ref 呼叫，找到 title, header, body, footer element
    tableTitleRef.current = e?.getElementsByClassName('ant-table-title')?.[0];
    tableHeaderRef.current = e?.getElementsByClassName('ant-table-header')?.[0];
    tableBodyRef.current = e?.getElementsByClassName('ant-table-body')?.[0];
    tableFooterRef.current = e?.getElementsByClassName('ant-table-footer')?.[0];
  };

  /** 38、48 分別是沒有換行時的基本高度，當作 element 找不到時的 fallback default 值 */
  const scroll = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      x: 1200,
      y:
        height -
        (tableTitleRef.current?.clientHeight || 38) -
        (tableHeaderRef.current?.clientHeight || 38) -
        (tableFooterRef.current?.clientHeight || 48)
    }
  }, [height]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (scroll) {
      // 直接指定高度
      if (tableBodyRef.current) tableBodyRef.current.style = `overflow: auto scroll; height: ${scroll.y}px;`;
    }
  }, [height, scroll]);

  return (
    <div ref={refs} style={{ height: '100%' }}>
      <Table
        scroll={scroll}
        sticky={true}
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={dataSource}
        pagination={false}
        showHeader={true}
        ...
        title={() => (
          <TaskTableTitle
            ...
          />
        )}
        footer={() => (
          <TaskTableFooter
            ...
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```